# How to compare different forecasting models over different time horizon?

Tags: lstm, model-evaluations, forecasting, sequence, arima

Developed multiple Models with AR, ARIMA, VAR; LSTM , SARIMA.
Now, the purpose is to find out which model performs best on a given use case with different time horizons.

The time series data is aggregated in weekly time-stamps.

A train-test split of 80/20 percent is performed. The question is: Which model is best for a 1 month, 6 months and 12 Months forecast?

How to evaluate those with RMSE?
Should the testset size change everytime? For example, use the 80% training data to train and predict on `testdata[:10]`, `testdata[:20]`, `testdata[:30]` and so on. Is there an other methology?

A simple AR Model and it seems like it is doing worse with a `testdata[:10]` prediction than with the whole testdata set.

Comment: Fixing the training set for all models and changing the tail size (test data) would be a good approach. However, repeatedly doing this with OOS rolling validation would give a better estimate of the performance of different models.

Comment: Hey what do you mean by rOOS?
But is it normal that the Forecast for 1 Time Stamp or for 10 of the AR Model is worse than the whole test data set which would be about 1 year?

Comment: rOOS, I was referring to technique introduced by Hydman, here https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/  . One would need to estimate with rOOS if AR model behaves like that.

Comment: @MehmetSüzen i see. But is this a scientific war of Comparing Models ? Or should i use 90% Training data for 10% testdata Evaluation and 80 for 20 and so on? Or is or okay to use 80% for arima lstm and AR and zehn only Manipulate the testdata[0:forecasthorizon]